# check if a list is the sum of k identical lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to solve this assignment:

> Write the function repeatingPattern(a) that takes a list a and returns True if a == b*k for some list b and some value k>1, and False otherwise. For example, repeatingPattern([1,2,3,1,2,3]) returns True (b==[1,2,3] and k=2).

My program works with some sample test cases, but occurs an IndexError or give wrong output when test with other test cases. I wonder how to let the program gives output as expected

```
def repeatingPattern(a):
    i=0
    k=1
    b=[]
    #Loop unti end of list a
    while i<len(a):
        #first value append into b
        if len(b)==0:
            b.append(a[i])
            i+=1
        #otherwise
        else:
            j=0
            cnt=0
            #Loop through b to check repetittion
            while j<len(b):
                if(b[j]==a[i]):
                    cnt+=1
                    i+=1
                #If not repeat return false
                elif b[j]!=a[i] and cnt!=0:
                    return False
                elif b[j]!=a[i] and k>1:
                    return False
                j+=1
            if cnt==len(b):
                k+=1
            else:
                b.append(a[i])
                i+=1
    #check condition for repeat generation then return true
    if(len(a)==len(b)*(k) and k>1):
        return True
    #Otherwise false
    else:
        return False
print(repeatingPattern([4,3,2,7,2,1]*2))
print(repeatingPattern([4,2,2]*2))
print(repeatingPattern([1,2,4,3,4]*2))
print(repeatingPattern([1,2,4,3,2]*2))
print(repeatingPattern([1,2,1]))
```

Expected:

```
True
True
True
True
False
```

Actual:

```
False
False
False
False
IndexError
```

Answer (score 1):

*I assume this is [homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and will answer it accordingly.*

You should try stating the [loop invariants](http://archives.evergreen.edu/webpages/curricular/2001-2002/dsa01/loops.html) you expect to hold and proving that they do. The way you wrote the code, it's hard to do that, which is why you get errors.

*"if a == b*k for some list b and some value k>1"* can instead be checked by trying the values of `k`, starting from `1` (what's the largest `k` you need to check?).

Now for the given `a` and `k`, if we assume `a == b*k` holds for some `b`, what is the value of `len(b)`?

If you know `len(b)` and know that `a` is the result of concatenating `b` with itself an unknown number of times, how do you find `b`?

At this point you have the specific values for `a`, `b`, and `k`, and can simply do:

```
if a == b * k:
   return True
```

If we checked all possible values of `k` and haven't found the solution, there isn't one:

```
return False
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to simplify your logic. This should work:

```
def isSame(arr, k, ind):
    if ind+k >= len(arr):
        return True
    if arr[ind] != arr[ind+k]:
        return False
    else:
        return isSame(arr, k, ind+k)

def repeatingPattern(arr):
    l = len(arr)
    if l <= 1:
        return False
    m=(l//2)+1
    for k in range(1, m):
        result = True
        if l%k!=0:
            continue
        for j in range(k):
            if not isSame(arr, k, j):
                result = False
        if result:
            return True
    return False


#Test cases
print(repeatingPattern([1,1]))
print(repeatingPattern([1]*3))
print(repeatingPattern([4,3,2,7,2,1]*2))
print(repeatingPattern([4,2,2,4,3,4]))
print(repeatingPattern([4,2,2]*3))
print(repeatingPattern([1,2,4,3,4]*4))
print(repeatingPattern([1,2,1]))
print(repeatingPattern([1,2,1,1,2,1,1,2,1]))
print(repeatingPattern([1,2,1,2,2,1]))
print(repeatingPattern([1,2,1,1,3,1]))
```

Comment: Simplify a program with more than 20 lines to less than 10 lines are very brilliant, but I cannot understand why initiaze m to len(arr) // 2 ? And do you know where are the problems in my program and how to let it gives correct output ?

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: @Nickolay could you please point out the use case that I missed?

Comment: Do you know how to solve this question by use only one function? And I am not familiar with recursion, can you just use loop (Best is while loop,because I can't use for loop in my exam) to solve this question?

Comment: @san `isSame` only checks that `arr[i*k]` are the same for all `i`, not what you intended it to do, but please don't update your solution yet, let @Eric try to come up with their own first.

Comment: @Nickolay. yeah, you are right. I missed a loop. I will wait for sometime before I update.

Comment: Updated the solution now.

Answer (score 0):

Another version, without recursion:

```
def divisors(n):
    divs = {1, n}
    for i in range(2,int(n**0.5)+1):
        if n%i == 0:
            divs.update((i,n//i))
    return sorted(divs)

def repeating_pattern(lst):
    for d in divisors(len(lst))[:-1]:
        l = [lst[i:i+d] for i in range(0, len(lst), d)]
        if all(i == j for i, j in zip(l[::1], l[1::1])):
            return True
    return False
```

Test cases:

```
print(repeating_pattern([1,1]))
print(repeating_pattern([1]*3))
print(repeating_pattern([4,3,2,7,2,1]*2))
print(repeating_pattern([4,2,2]*2))
print(repeating_pattern([4,2,2]*3))
print(repeating_pattern([1,2,4,3,4]*2))
print(repeating_pattern([1,2,4,3,2]*2))
print(repeating_pattern([1,2,1]))
print(repeating_pattern([1,2,1,1,2,1,2,2,1]))
```

Prints:

```
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
False
False
```